# change format with yaml dump python

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I need to create a yaml with the following format

```
hints:
    - {
        content: "...",
        ...
      }
```

alredy tried to do something like `data['hints'] = {"content" : "a", "foo" : "bar"}` giving:

```
hints:
- content: "a"
  foo: "bar"
```

also tried `data['hints'] = "{\n" + f"content:{...}," + "\n" + ... + "\n}"`, giving:

```
hints:
- '{

  content: ...,

  foo:bar,

  }'
```

Comment: Given that both formats are equivalent, do you really *need* the `{}`?

Comment: The only situation I can see where you would need (1) but (2) could not be used is if the code that reads it is non-standard (i.e. not a YAML library). In this case, your best bet is to fix that code. If you can't, then I guess you should also use custom code (and not a YAML library).

Comment: yes, I use a library that expects to receive that format in the yml. Now I'm trying to do that replacement with the sed command, but I'm looking for other solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the style with a custom representer, like so:

```py
import sys, yaml

class BraceDict(dict):
    pass


def represent_brace_dict(dumper, data):
    ret = dumper.represent_dict(data)
    ret.flow_style = True
    return ret
yaml.add_representer(BraceDict, represent_brace_dict)

yaml.dump({
    "hints": [
        BraceDict(content = "a", foo = "bar")
    ]
}, sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```yaml
hints:
- {content: a, foo: bar}
```

If you want to force quotes on values, use [the same technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67477544/347964) for them.

You can't force multiline output though. In any case,

> I use a library that expects to receive that format in the yml

that sounds very strange, as the YAML spec requires that both formats must be supported. If a library doesn't implement this, it technically doesn't use YAML and therefore you shouldn't use a YAML library to generate its input.